# general.el definer send universal-argument

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

Given a definer, for example:

```
(general-create-definer test-def
  :states '(normal insert motion emacs)
  :keymaps 'override
  :prefix "SPC")
(test-def "" nil
          "f" 'find-file
          ...)
```

I would like to press `u` to get the behaviour of pressing the `C-u` prefix.

For example, the following pairs of keypresses should work equivalently:

- `SPC u f` same as `C-u SPC f`
- `SPC u u f` same as `C-u C-u SPC f`

This solution should work for all the keys in the definer.

#### Solution attempt:

If I set

```
(test-def "u" 'universal-argument)
(general-def universal-argument-map "u" 'universal-argument-more)
```

then to get behaviour equivalent to `C-u C-u SPC f` I have to press `SPC u u SPC f`. I don't want to have to press `SPC` the second time.

Answer (score 1):

**A reasonably satisfactory approach**

```
;; change prefix argument, and activate transient keymap 'map'
(defun tap/prefix-map-add-numeric-prefix (map)
  (interactive)
  (prefix-command-preserve-state)
  (universal-argument-more (list (prefix-numeric-value prefix-arg)))
  (set-transient-map map))

(general-create-definer space-def
  :states '(normal insert motion emacs)
  :keymaps 'override
  :prefix-map 'space-def-map
  :prefix "SPC"
  :non-normal-prefix "M-SPC")
(space-def "" nil) ;; makes this an incomplete prefix

;; change prefix argument, and activate transient keymap space-def-map 
(space-def "u" '((lambda () (interactive) (tap/prefix-map-add-numeric-prefix space-def-map)) :which-key "add C-u"))
```

Demonstration

```
(defun prefixval (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (message (format "%d" (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))))
(space-def "p" 'prefixval)

;; SPC p (1)
;; SPC u p (4)
;; SPC u u p (16)
;; etc.
```

NB: After pressing `SPC u`, `which-key` completions will no longer be visible. It is possible to try to include them, but I am happy enough without them, because if I forget the keys, I can just press `SPC` instead of `SPC u`, and find the key.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(general-define-key
 :states '(normal insert motion emacs)
 :keymaps 'override
 :prefix-map 'tyrant-map
 :prefix "SPC"
 :non-normal-prefix "M-SPC")

(general-create-definer tyrant-def :keymaps 'tyrant-map)
(tyrant-def "" nil)
(general-def universal-argument-map
  "u" 'universal-argument-more)
(tyrant-def
  "SPC"     '("M-x" . execute-extended-command)
  "u"       '("universal arg" . universal-argument))
```

Comment: Using this, I still have to press SPC the second time. Therefore, I don't see what it improves over my initial solution attempt. Please explain in what way it is different.

Comment: The key is `(general-def universal-argument-map  "u" 'universal-argument-more)`,  and I can press `SPC u u` to get `C-u C-u` on my side.

Comment: Yes, I can press `SPC u u` to get `C-u C-u` (but I was already able to do that). The problem is, in your example, to run `execute-extended-command` with two prefix arguments, I need to press `SPC u u SPC SPC`, but I want to just be able to press `SPC u u SPC`. i.e. I don't want to have to press the `SPC` prefix command twice. In my original question I have given other examples. Thanks

Comment: I suppose you could try changing the SPC prefix-map to `universal-argument-map` but that would cause the binding `SPC digit` to override the `C-u digit` function.

Comment: I want the solution to generalise well. For example, I may have many definers with different prefixes: SPC, DEL, etc. Setting all of their prefix-maps to `universal-argument-map` would dump all the bindings from SPC, DEL, etc. into the same map. My posted answer below achieves roughly the desired behaviour